# Negative API testing in JEST

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

When I give valid credentials it is passed. But I want to test my login API in jest with invalid credential and expect the status code as 401. How to do that?

```
  it('fails with invalid credentials', async () => {
  const  res = await axios.post('/rest/api/login', data);
    console.log('Status:', response.status);
    expect(response.status).toBe(401);
  });
```

Getting the following error message

```
Request failed with status code 401

      at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
      at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
      at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:191:11)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.285 s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
expect(() => await axios.post('/rest/api/login', data)).toThrow('Request failed with status code 401');
```

or

```
 try {
      await axios.post('/rest/api/login', data);
      expect(true).toBe(false);
  } catch (e) {
      expect(e.message).toBe("Request failed with status code 401");
  }
```